# How to add both radio and check buttons using visual basic 2008

Tags: vb.net

I have had to use if/else if statements to add the radio buttons and check buttons, but I need it to be so that when a person selects the check button and radio button that it will add up.

I tried to use if then a select case but just get an error when doing that.

my code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Calculate.Click
    'calculate value of subtotal

    Me.Subtotal.Text = Val(Me.CarTextBox.Text)

    If Pearlized.Checked = True Then

        Me.Subtotal.Text = Val(Me.CarTextBox.Text) + 345.72

    ElseIf Customized.Checked = True Then

        Me.Subtotal.Text = Val(Me.CarTextBox.Text) + 599.99

    ElseIf Stereo.Checked = True Then

        Me.Subtotal.Text = Val(Me.CarTextBox.Text) + 425.76

    ElseIf Leather.Checked = True Then

        Me.Subtotal.Text = Val(Me.CarTextBox.Text) + 987.41

    ElseIf Comp.Checked = True Then

        Me.Subtotal.Text = Val(Me.CarTextBox.Text) + 1741.23

    End If

    'calculate tax

    Me.Total.Text = Val(Me.Subtotal.Text) * 1.08

    'calculate amount due

    Me.AmountDue.Text = Val(Me.Total.Text) - Val(TradeTextBox.Text)

End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Which are the radio buttons and the check buttons here?

Answer (score 0):

Setup a subtotal variable at the beginning of your method.
Add to it as you test through each checkbox.
Perform calcs at the end.

I would suggest keeping your values for pearlized, customized, stereo, tax rate etc in a config or associated text file. It will save you in the future when they change.

```
Private Sub calculateTotal()

    Try

        'calculate value of subtotal
        Dim subTotal As Double = CDbl(CarTextBox.Text)    

        If Pearlized.Checked = True Then
            subTotal += subTotal + 345.72
        End If

        If Customized.Checked = True Then
            subTotal += subTotal + 599.99
        End If

        If Stereo.Checked = True Then
            subTotal += subTotal + 425.76
        End If

        If Leather.Checked = True Then
            subTotal += subTotal + 987.41
        End If

        If Comp.Checked = True Then
            subTotal += subTotal + 1741.23
        End If

        'calculate tax    
        Me.SubTotal.Text = subTotal
        Me.Total.Text = subTotal * 1.08

        'calculate amount due    
        Me.AmountDue.Text = Val(Me.Total.Text) - Val(TradeTextBox.Text)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred: ", ex.Message))
    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `Decimal` rather than `Double`.

Comment: the only problem I am getting is that The radio buttons Pearlized or Customized only can be selected so when someone selects the CheckedBox buttons like Stereo, Leather, Comp that the Subtotal must calculate the selected radio button and the selected checkbox items together